# Not able to connect to Azure SQL database, Error 10060

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created a sql database in the azure (PAAS) and trying to connect using SSMS 2017.

**Unfortunately, I do not have admin rights to my machine.** considering this, Can you please let me know what are my options in connecting to azure sql db?

Here is the error I am seeing.

[image]

Comment: check this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcloud/2017/07/29/azure-learning-1-connectivity-errors-from-external-network-to-azure-database/

Comment: Your local account doesn't matter at all, you're trying to connect to a *remote* machine. Hosted databases aren't exposed to the public unless the *owner* (you) configures them. Have you configured Azure's firewall to expose that IP to your network?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I already configured my IP address. it is not helpful.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli This is helpful, 
ping did not work, tracert tells that it is getting blocked at corporate account. As I am not the windows administrator, I couldn't enable telnet. Are there any other workarounds for this?

Comment: Try this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b9232115-46b4-44a1-a90d-dbd0904a5bb7/connecting-to-azure-sql-database-with-ssms-microsoft-sql-server-error-10060

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Tried all those, added free for all ip range from 0's to 255's. Looks like the problem is my outbound 1433 port is blocked by my corporate network. As per the description, I am not admin for this computer, so can't even disable any firewalls or do the telnet operation.

Comment: You've already stated that the problem is outbound on 1433 is blocked by your corporate network.  Sound like you need to have a conversation with whomever manages that.

Comment: @TimMylott, As mentioned in my original post, I was looking for other options instead of opening up 1433.

Answer (score 0):

Since your company network has port 1433 blocked, you can try the following. Most companies have a free WIFI for guests or visitors, use that WIFI to connect to your company using a VPN client like FortiClient, Citrix Workspace or SonicWall NetExtender. While connected to your company network with these clients you may still be able to connect to Azure SQL Database.

Make sure Windows Firewall or other security software do not have port 1433 blocked also.